# SOAP no devuelve el resultado con datos

Tags: php, soap, symfony

Tengo la siguiente definición de un WS:

```
<s:element name="ObtenerAlbaranesVentas">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="empresa" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="cifCliente" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="almacen" type="s:string" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="desde" type="s:date" nullable="false" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="hasta" type="s:date" nullable="false" />
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0" name="serie" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="ObtenerAlbaranesVentasResponse">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AlbaranesVenta" type="tns:ArrayOfAlbaranesVenta"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfAlbaranesVenta">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="AlbaranVenta" type="tns:AlbaranVenta" nullable="true"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="AlbaranVenta">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CabeceraAlbaran" type="tns:CabeceraAlbaran"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LineasAlbaran" type="tns:ArrayOfAlbaranVentasLin"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>

<s:complexType name="CabeceraAlbaran">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="empresa" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="codigoalbaran" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="codigoserie" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="fechaAlbaran" type="s:date"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="baseImponible" type="s:float"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="totalIva" type="s:float"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="totalAlbaran" type="s:float"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cifCliente" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cifSocio" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="idCentroCompra" type="s:string"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfAlbaranVentasLin">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="LineaAlbaran" nullable="true" type="tns:LineaAlbaran"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="LineaAlbaran">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="linea" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="referencia" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="referenciaComercial" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="descripcion" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="marca" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="marcaGrupo" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="familiaGrupo" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cantidad" type="s:float"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="precio" type="s:float"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="dto" type="s:float"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="netolinea" type="s:float"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="tasa" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="impuesto" type="s:boolean"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="descripcionTasaImpuesto" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="importeTasaImpuesto" type="s:float"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<wsdl:message name="ObtenerAlbaranesVentasSoapIn">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ObtenerAlbaranesVentas"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="ObtenerAlbaranesVentasSoapOut">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:ObtenerAlbaranesVentasResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:operation name="ObtenerAlbaranesVentas">
<wsdl:input message="tns:ObtenerAlbaranesVentasSoapIn"/>
<wsdl:output message="tns:ObtenerAlbaranesVentasSoapOut"/>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="ObtenerAlbaranesVentas">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://skrit.es/ObtenerAlbaranesVentas" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="ObtenerAlbaranesVentas">
<soap12:operation soapAction="http://skrit.es/ObtenerAlbaranesVentas" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

Cada elemento tiene su fichero php correspondiente:

```
<?php
/**
 * @license privative
 *
 * @author Pavlo Bodnar <pavlo@XXX.com>
 */
namespace App\Entity\Serca;

/**
 * Class ObtenerAlbaranesVentas
 */
class ObtenerAlbaranesVentas
{
    /** @var string $empresa */
    protected $empresa;

    /** @var string $cifCliente */
    protected $cifCliente;

    /** @var string $almacen */
    protected $almacen;

    /** @var \DateTimeImmutable $desde */
    protected $desde;

    /** @var \DateTimeImmutable $hasta */
    protected $hasta;

    /** @var string $serie */
    protected $serie;


    /**
     * ObtenerAlbaranesVentas constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(\stdClass $parameters)
    {
        $this->empresa = $parameters->{'empresa'};
        $this->cifCliente = $parameters->{'cifCliente'};
        $this->almacen = $parameters->{'almacen'};
        $this->desde = new \DateTimeImmutable($parameters->{'desde'});
        $this->hasta = new \DateTimeImmutable($parameters->{'hasta'});
        $this->serie = $parameters->{'serie'};
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmpresa(): string
    {
        return $this->empresa;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $empresa
     */
    public function setEmpresa(string $empresa): void
    {
        $this->empresa = $empresa;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCifCliente(): string
    {
        return $this->cifCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cifCliente
     */
    public function setCifCliente(string $cifCliente): void
    {
        $this->cifCliente = $cifCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAlmacen(): string
    {
        return $this->almacen;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $almacen
     */
    public function setAlmacen(string $almacen): void
    {
        $this->almacen = $almacen;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTimeImmutable
     */
    public function getDesde(): \DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->desde;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTimeImmutable $desde
     */
    public function setDesde(\DateTimeImmutable $desde): void
    {
        $this->desde = $desde;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTimeImmutable
     */
    public function getHasta(): \DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->hasta;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTimeImmutable $hasta
     */
    public function setHasta(\DateTimeImmutable $hasta): void
    {
        $this->hasta = $hasta;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSerie(): string
    {
        return $this->serie;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $serie
     */
    public function setSerie(string $serie): void
    {
        $this->serie = $serie;
    }

}

#######################################################################################

<?php
/**
 * Consultar albaranes response
 */
namespace App\Entity\Serca;

/**
 * Class ObteneralbaranesVentasResponse
 */
class ObtenerAlbaranesVentasResponse
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayOfAlbaranesVenta
     */
    protected $AlbaranesVenta;

    /**
     * @param array $AlbaranesVenta
     */
    public function __construct($AlbaranesVenta)
    {
        $this->AlbaranesVenta = $AlbaranesVenta;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayOfAlbaranesVenta
     */
    public function getAlbaranesVenta(): ArrayOfAlbaranesVenta
    {
        return $this->AlbaranesVenta;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayOfAlbaranesVenta $AlbaranesVenta
     *
     * @return ObtenerAlbaranesVentasResponse
     */
    public function setAlbaranesVenta($AlbaranesVenta): ObtenerAlbaranesVentasResponse
    {
        $this->Marcas = $AlbaranesVenta;

        return $this;
    }
}
#######################################################################################
<?php


namespace App\Entity\Serca;


class ArrayOfAlbaranesVenta
{
    /** @var AlbaranVenta[] */
    protected $AlbaranVenta;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return AlbaranVenta[]
     */
    public function getAlbaran(): array
    {
        return $this->AlbaranVenta;
    }

    /**
     * @param AlbaranVenta[] $Albaran
     */
    public function setAlbaran(array $Albaran): void
    {
        $this->AlbaranVenta = $Albaran;
    }
}
#######################################################################################
<?php


namespace App\Entity\Serca;


class AlbaranVenta
{
    /** @var CabeceraAlbaran $CabeceraAlbaran */
    protected $CabeceraAlbaran;

    /** @var ArrayOfAlbaranVentasLin $LineasAlbaran */
    protected $LineasAlbaran;

    public function __construct(array $datos)
    {
        $this->CabeceraAlbaran = $datos['cabecera'];
        $this->LineasAlbaran = $datos['lineas'];
    }

    /**
     * @return CabeceraAlbaran
     */
    public function getCabeceraAlbaran(): CabeceraAlbaran
    {
        return $this->CabeceraAlbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @param CabeceraAlbaran $CabeceraAlbaran
     */
    public function setCabeceraAlbaran(CabeceraAlbaran $CabeceraAlbaran): void
    {
        $this->CabeceraAlbaran = $CabeceraAlbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @return ArrayOfAlbaranVentasLin
     */
    public function getLineasAlbaran(): ArrayOfAlbaranVentasLin
    {
        return $this->LineasAlbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayOfAlbaranVentasLin $LineasAlbaran
     */
    public function setLineasAlbaran(ArrayOfAlbaranVentasLin $LineasAlbaran): void
    {
        $this->LineasAlbaran = $LineasAlbaran;
    }
}
#######################################################################################
<?php
/**
 * @licence privative Recanvis XXX
 *
 * @author Pavlo Bodnar <pavlo@XXX.com>
 */
namespace App\Entity\Serca;

/**
 * Class CabeceraAlbaran
 */
class CabeceraAlbaran
{
    /**
     * @var string $empresa
     */
    protected $empresa;

    /**
     * @var string $codigoalbaran
     */
    protected $codigoalbaran;

    /**
     * @var string $codigoserie
     */
    protected $codigoserie;

    /**
     * @var \DateTimeInterface $fechaAlbaran
     */
    protected $fechaAlbaran;

    /**
     * @var float $baseImponible
     */
    protected $baseImponible;

    /**
     * @var float $totalIva
     */
    protected $totalIva;

    /**
     * @var float $totalAlbaran
     */
    protected $totalAlbaran;

    /**
     * @var string $cifCliente
     */
    protected $cifCliente;

    /**
     * @var string $cifSocio
     */
    protected $cifSocio;

    /**
     * @var string $idCentroCompra
     */
    protected $idCentroCompra;

    /**
     * CabeceraAlbaran constructor.
     *
     * @param mixed[] $datos
     */
    public function __construct(array $datos)
    {
        $this->empresa = $datos['empresa'];
        $this->codigoalbaran = $datos['codigoalbaran'];
        $this->codigoserie = $datos['codigoserie'];
        $this->fechaAlbaran = $datos['fechaAlbaran'];
        $this->baseImponible = $datos['baseImponible'];
        $this->totalIva = $datos['totalIva'];
        $this->totalAlbaran = $datos['totalAlbaran'];
        $this->cifCliente = $datos['CifCliente'];
        $this->cifSocio = $datos['CifSocio'];
        $this->idCentroCompra = $datos['IdCentroCompra'];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCodigo(): string
    {
        return $this->codigo;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $codigo
     */
    public function setCodigo(string $codigo): void
    {
        $this->codigo = $codigo;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmpresa(): string
    {
        return $this->empresa;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $empresa
     */
    public function setEmpresa(string $empresa): void
    {
        $this->empresa = $empresa;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCodigoalbaran(): string
    {
        return $this->codigoalbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $codigoalbaran
     */
    public function setCodigoalbaran(string $codigoalbaran): void
    {
        $this->codigoalbaran = $codigoalbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCodigoserie(): string
    {
        return $this->codigoserie;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $codigoserie
     */
    public function setCodigoserie(string $codigoserie): void
    {
        $this->codigoserie = $codigoserie;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTimeInterface
     */
    public function getFechaAlbaran(): \DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->fechaAlbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTimeInterface $fechaAlbaran
     */
    public function setFechaAlbaran(\DateTimeInterface $fechaAlbaran): void
    {
        $this->fechaAlbaran = $fechaAlbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getBaseImponible(): float
    {
        return $this->baseImponible;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $baseImponible
     */
    public function setBaseImponible(float $baseImponible): void
    {
        $this->baseImponible = $baseImponible;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTotalIva(): float
    {
        return $this->totalIva;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $totalIva
     */
    public function setTotalIva(float $totalIva): void
    {
        $this->totalIva = $totalIva;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getTotalAlbaran(): float
    {
        return $this->totalAlbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $totalAlbaran
     */
    public function setTotalAlbaran(float $totalAlbaran): void
    {
        $this->totalAlbaran = $totalAlbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCifCliente(): string
    {
        return $this->cifCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cifCliente
     */
    public function setCifCliente(string $cifCliente): void
    {
        $this->cifCliente = $cifCliente;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCifSocio(): string
    {
        return $this->cifSocio;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $cifSocio
     */
    public function setCifSocio(string $cifSocio): void
    {
        $this->cifSocio = $cifSocio;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getIdCentroCompra(): string
    {
        return $this->idCentroCompra;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $idCentroCompra
     */
    public function setIdCentroCompra(string $idCentroCompra): void
    {
        $this->idCentroCompra = $idCentroCompra;
    }
}
#######################################################################################
<?php
/**
 * arrayOfMarcasERP
 */

namespace App\Entity\Serca;

/**
 * Class ArrayOfLineaAlbaran
 */
class ArrayOfAlbaranVentasLin implements \ArrayAccess, \Iterator, \Countable
{
    /**
     * @var LineaAlbaran[]
     */
    protected $LineaAlbaran;

    /**
     * ArrayOfLineaAlbaran constructor.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * @return LineaAlbaran[]
     */
    public function getLineaAlbaran()
    {
        return $this->LineaAlbaran;
    }

    /**
     * @param LineaAlbaran[] $LineaAlbaran
     *
     * @return arrayOfMarcasERP
     */
    public function setLineaAlbaran(array $LineaAlbaran = null)
    {
        $this->LineaAlbaran = $LineaAlbaran;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * ArrayAccess implementation.
     *
     * @param mixed $offset An offset to check for
     *
     * @return bool true on success or false on failure
     */
    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->LineaAlbaran[$offset]);
    }

    /**
     * ArrayAccess implementation.
     *
     * @param mixed $offset The offset to retrieve
     *
     * @return LineaAlbaran
     */
    public function offsetGet($offset)
    {
        return $this->LineaAlbaran[$offset];
    }

    /**
     * ArrayAccess implementation.
     *
     * @param mixed $offset The offset to assign the value to
     * @param LineaAlbaran $value  The value to set
     */
    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        if (!isset($offset)) {
            $this->LineaAlbaran[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->LineaAlbaran[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    /**
     * ArrayAccess implementation.
     *
     * @param mixed $offset The offset to unset
     */
    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        unset($this->LineaAlbaran[$offset]);
    }

    /**
     * Iterator implementation.
     *
     * @return LineaAlbaran Return the current element
     */
    public function current()
    {
        return current($this->LineaAlbaran);
    }

    /**
     * Iterator implementation
     * Move forward to next element.
     */
    public function next()
    {
        next($this->LineaAlbaran);
    }

    /**
     * Iterator implementation.
     *
     * @return string|null Return the key of the current element or null
     */
    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->LineaAlbaran);
    }

    /**
     * Iterator implementation.
     *
     * @return bool Return the validity of the current position
     */
    public function valid()
    {
        return null !== $this->key();
    }

    /**
     * Iterator implementation
     * Rewind the Iterator to the first element.
     */
    public function rewind()
    {
        reset($this->LineaAlbaran);
    }

    /**
     * Countable implementation.
     *
     * @return LineaAlbaran Return count of elements
     */
    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->LineaAlbaran);
    }
}
#######################################################################################
<?php


namespace App\Entity\Serca;


class LineaAlbaran
{
    /**
     * @var string $linea
     */
    protected $linea;

    /**
     * @var string $referencia
     */
    protected $referencia;

    /**
     * @var string $referenciaComercial
     */
    protected $referenciaComercial;

    /**
     * @var string $descripcion
     */
    protected $descripcion;

    /**
     * @var string $marca
     */
    protected $marca;

    /**
     * @var string $marcaGrupo
     */
    protected $marcaGrupo;

    /**
     * @var string $familiaGrupo
     */
    protected $familiaGrupo;

    /**
     * @var float $cantidad
     */
    protected $cantidad;

    /**
     * @var float $precio
     */
    protected $precio;

    /**
     * @var float $dto
     */
    protected $dto;

    /**
     * @var float $netolinea
     */
    protected $netolinea;

    /**
     * @var boolean $tasa
     */
    protected $tasa;

    /**
     * @var boolean $impuesto
     */
    protected $impuesto;

    /**
     * @var string $descripcionTasaImpuesto
     */
    protected $descripcionTasaImpuesto;

    /**
     * @var float $importeTasaImpuesto
     */
    protected $importeTasaImpuesto;

    /**
     * LineaAlbaran constructor.
     *
     * @param mixed[] $datos
     */
    public function __construct(array $datos)
    {
        $this->linea = $datos['linea'];
        $this->referencia = $datos['referencia'];
        $this->referenciaComercial = $datos['referenciaComercial'];
        $this->descripcion = $datos['descripcion'];
        $this->marca = $datos['marca'];
        $this->marcaGrupo = $datos['marcaGrupo'];
        $this->familiaGrupo = $datos['familiaGrupo'];
        $this->cantidad = $datos['cantidad'];
        $this->precio = $datos['precio'];
        $this->dto = $datos['dto'];
        $this->netolinea = $datos['netolinea'];
        $this->tasa = $datos['tasa'];
        $this->impuesto = $datos['impuesto'];
        $this->descripcionTasaImpuesto = $datos['descripcionTasaImpuesto'];
        $this->importeTasaImpuesto = $datos['importeTasaImpuesto'];
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCodigo(): string
    {
        return $this->codigo;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $codigo
     */
    public function setCodigo(string $codigo): void
    {
        $this->codigo = $codigo;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLinea(): string
    {
        return $this->linea;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $linea
     */
    public function setLinea(string $linea): void
    {
        $this->linea = $linea;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReferencia(): string
    {
        return $this->referencia;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $referencia
     */
    public function setReferencia(string $referencia): void
    {
        $this->referencia = $referencia;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReferenciaComercial(): string
    {
        return $this->referenciaComercial;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $referenciaComercial
     */
    public function setReferenciaComercial(string $referenciaComercial): void
    {
        $this->referenciaComercial = $referenciaComercial;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescripcion(): string
    {
        return $this->descripcion;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $descripcion
     */
    public function setDescripcion(string $descripcion): void
    {
        $this->descripcion = $descripcion;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMarca(): string
    {
        return $this->marca;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $marca
     */
    public function setMarca(string $marca): void
    {
        $this->marca = $marca;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMarcaGrupo(): string
    {
        return $this->marcaGrupo;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $marcaGrupo
     */
    public function setMarcaGrupo(string $marcaGrupo): void
    {
        $this->marcaGrupo = $marcaGrupo;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFamiliaGrupo(): string
    {
        return $this->familiaGrupo;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $familiaGrupo
     */
    public function setFamiliaGrupo(string $familiaGrupo): void
    {
        $this->familiaGrupo = $familiaGrupo;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getCantidad(): float
    {
        return $this->cantidad;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $cantidad
     */
    public function setCantidad(float $cantidad): void
    {
        $this->cantidad = $cantidad;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrecio(): float
    {
        return $this->precio;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $precio
     */
    public function setPrecio(float $precio): void
    {
        $this->precio = $precio;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getDto(): float
    {
        return $this->dto;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $dto
     */
    public function setDto(float $dto): void
    {
        $this->dto = $dto;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getNetolinea(): float
    {
        return $this->netolinea;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $netolinea
     */
    public function setNetolinea(float $netolinea): void
    {
        $this->netolinea = $netolinea;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isTasa(): bool
    {
        return $this->tasa;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $tasa
     */
    public function setTasa(bool $tasa): void
    {
        $this->tasa = $tasa;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isImpuesto(): bool
    {
        return $this->impuesto;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $impuesto
     */
    public function setImpuesto(bool $impuesto): void
    {
        $this->impuesto = $impuesto;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescripcionTasaImpuesto(): string
    {
        return $this->descripcionTasaImpuesto;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $descripcionTasaImpuesto
     */
    public function setDescripcionTasaImpuesto(string $descripcionTasaImpuesto): void
    {
        $this->descripcionTasaImpuesto = $descripcionTasaImpuesto;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getImporteTasaImpuesto(): float
    {
        return $this->importeTasaImpuesto;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $importeTasaImpuesto
     */
    public function setImporteTasaImpuesto(float $importeTasaImpuesto): void
    {
        $this->importeTasaImpuesto = $importeTasaImpuesto;
    }

}
```

Cuando hago una llamada de prueba utilizando `Postman`, en el profiler cuando hago el dump de lo que devuelve me devuelve la estructura correcta:

```
App\Entity\Serca\ObtenerAlbaranesVentasResponse {#661 ▼
  #AlbaranesVenta: array:23 [▼
    0 => App\Entity\Serca\AlbaranVenta {#652 ▼
      #CabeceraAlbaran: App\Entity\Serca\CabeceraAlbaran {#637 ▼
        #empresa: "01"
        #codigoalbaran: "  20000018"
        #codigoserie: "P1"
        #fechaAlbaran: "2020-01-02 00:00:00"
        #baseImponible: 14,7
        #totalIva: 3,087
        #totalAlbaran: 17,787
        #cifCliente: "xxx      "
        #cifSocio: ""
        #idCentroCompra: "PO"
      }
      #LineasAlbaran: array:1 [▼
        0 => App\Entity\Serca\LineaAlbaran {#673 ▶}
      ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Sin embargo no me rellena bien los datos a la hora de devolver el xml del soap, si no qu eme devuelve esto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.serca.es/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:ObtenerAlbaranesVentasResponse>
            <ns1:AlbaranesVenta/>
        </ns1:ObtenerAlbaranesVentasResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Si llega hasta este punto se entiende que nada ha fallado salvo que en algún punt el soap no coincide con las clases php, pero lo he revisado muchas veces durante varias horas hoy y no veo el problema....

Comment: ¿Cuál cliente SOAP usas y cómo obtienes el xml?

Comment: A mi me parece que el wsdl esta mal elaborado. ¿Alguien había visto con anterioridad un wsdl soap con la url definida dos veces?

Comment: Bueno, para empezar: ese XML no es válido. Sólo puede haber un nodo raíz y ahí veo 11.  Tienes la url con el WSDL?

Comment: A qué te refieres con que oslo puede haber un nodo raíz?

Comment: @ffflabs No sé si es correcto o no, el caso es que todas las demás llamadas funcionan sin problema alguno pero esta no. No soy experto en SOAP, es una cosa que me ha tocado hacer de rebote...